# Is there a better way to implement this OOP(ish) in Rust?

Tags: oop, rust

In particular I feel like putting Sphere(Sphere) in the Shape enum feels wrong and that implementing Volume for shape this way seems like a roudabout way of doing things:

```
struct Particle {
    mass: f64,
    shape: Shape
}

enum Shape {
    Sphere(Sphere)
}

impl Volume for Shape {
    fn calculate_volume(&self) -> f64 {
        match self {
            Shape::Sphere(sphere) => 4.0 / 3.0 * consts::PI * sphere.radius.powi(3),
            _ => panic!("Not valid")
        }
    }
}

impl Particle {
    pub fn calculate_density(&self) -> f64{
        self.mass * self.shape.calculate_volume()
    }
}

struct Sphere {
    radius: f64
}

trait Volume {
    fn calculate_volume(&self) -> f64;
}
```

I was previously trying to implement this with the enum:

```
enum Shape {
    Sphere
}
```

Instead of:

```
enum Shape {
    Sphere(Sphere)
}
```

If my predisposition to the code above is misplaced please tell me what the use of it is. Note that I've added this code without even really knowing what I'm doing...

Edit: I plan on adding more shapes in the future then just Sphere.

Comment: Why do you need `enum Shape` at all? Just implement `Volume` for `Sphere` directly⁉

Comment: Note that `_ => panic!("Not valid")` is dead code. You've already matched all possibilities, so this code cannot be reached. I would remove it, as doing so will allow the compiler to tell you where you need to consider new enum variants should you add more later.

Comment: I'm not at all a Rust expert, but from the little I've done, it requires a mind-shift: you want to rely a lot less on runtime polymorphism, and a lot more on the generics system and _compile_-time polymorphism. I think that's what @cafce25 is getting at. Rather than having `impl Volume for Shape`, have `impl Volume for Sphere` and then basically have every method that uses Volume take `V: Volume` instead of a `dyn Volume`.

Comment: Sorry, I believe this is my fault for not giving some more context, but I plan on making more shapes in the future, so removing the Shape enum would make it difficult (or impossible) to write Particle.

Comment: @CocytusDEDI I think again, `Particle` should really be `Particle<V: Volume>`. And then if you ever need a collection of heterogeneous particles, _that's_ where you'd do the dynamic dispatch, with `Box<Particle<dyn Volume>>` (or something like that). But again, I'm not an expert, so take that with a grain of salt.

Comment: @yshavit There isn't anything wrong with the enum approach. I think what OP wants is mostly what you've said, but also to `impl Volume for Shape` and then they can do the dispatch there. This gives them dynamic dispatch through an enum instead of `dyn`, which is a very common pattern in Rust.

Comment: If the `Sphere(Sphere)` looks weird to you, you could inline the inner struct and instead have, in your enum, `Sphere{radius: f64}`. 

But I'd say that _knowing_ how to compute the volume of a sphere belongs to the sphere struct, so instead I'd have `impl Volume for Sphere` and then as @cdhowie suggests I'd implement `Volume` for `Shape` and just dispatch it.

Comment: @cdhowie Thanks! See, like I said, I'm not an expert. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In particular I feel like putting Sphere(Sphere) in the Shape enum feels wrong

This is actually a very common pattern in Rust, and it isn't wrong at all! It's similar to OOP where you use runtime dynamic dispatch. This exists in Rust as `dyn`, but in many cases you can do exactly what you're doing here -- build an enum, then dispatch statically.

However, the actual implementation of volume calculation for `Sphere` should be moved to that struct.  Then the implementation for `Shape` can just delegate to it.

```
trait Volume {
    fn calculate_volume(&self) -> f64;
}

struct Sphere {
    radius: f64
}

impl Volume for Sphere {
    fn calculate_volume(&self) -> f64 {
        4.0 / 3.0 * consts::PI * self.radius.powi(3)
    }
}

enum Shape {
    Sphere(Sphere)
}

impl Volume for Shape {
    fn calculate_volume(&self) -> f64 {
        match self {
            Self::Sphere(s) => s.calculate_volume(),
        }
    }
}
```

This allows you to bound a generic type on `Volume` and then it can accept `Shape` or any variant (e.g. `Sphere`) directly.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I've implemented it as you said. And about the Sphere (Sphere) thing, I was confused because I didn't realise the first 'Sphere' was just a name and didn't tie the enum back to the struct, so when I gave the name Sphere the value of Sphere it seemed redundant to me, but I think I get it now.